# How to initialize null terminated char array in class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, char

I was wondering if there is any other way to fill char array with null terminates in class constructor apart from using for loop. With for loop it works fine. But I assume there should be an easier way... Or I am wrong?

```
String::String()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
       stringNew[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: you could use something like memcpy

Comment: You don't need to zerofill the array for it to be a valid null-terminated string. The first zero is the only one that matters.

Comment: try:  `char array[SIZE] = {0};` or `memset ( array, 0, SIZE );`
Memset requires that you include either string.h or string, but it won't give warnings on some compilers.

Comment: char array[SIZE] = {0}; gives me warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Comment: Whether you're using C++11 or a previous version of the language matters here since the behavior for initializing an array in the ctor initializer list changed.

Answer (score 1):

If `stringNew` is a `std::string`, you could call the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
//Initializes 'stringNew' with 80 times '\0'
String::String() : stringNew(80, '\0') {}
```

If it is a `char[]`, you could call [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
String::String()
{
    std::fill(std::begin(stringNew), std::end(stringNew), '\0');
}
```

You could also use the loop, like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

```
class String
{
   String() : stringNew() {}
   char stringNew[40];
};
```

C++ automatically initializes the vector with zeros. Since (int)'\0'==0, you got what you needed.